# jQuery deferred works with jQuery v1.x and v2.x but not with v3.x

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, deferred

This fiddle is about jquery deferred objects. Execution order is `1,4,2,3` . It works as expected with jquery `v1.x` and `v2.x` but not `v3.x` . What am I missing?

Proper order is `1,4,2,3,all done` but in `v3` it's `1,2,4,all done,3` which doesn't make sense `when/all done` triggers before `3`

**Simply just change jQuery version and you'll see that with `v3.x` it doesn't work in the `1,4,2,3` order.**

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/ergec/mrd2dt3a/

and these are the codes.

**css**

```
div {
    width: 0px;
    height: 20px;
}

.div1 {
    background-color: red;
}

.div2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.div3 {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.div4 {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

**javascript**

```
var defer = $.Deferred();
var div1 = defer.then(function(value) {
    return $(".div1").animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, 1000);
});
var div2 = div1.then(function(value) {
    $("#status").append("<p>div1 done</p>");
    return $(".div2").animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, 3000);
});
var div3 = div2.then(function(value) {
    $("#status").append("<p>div2 done</p>");
    return $(".div3").animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, 2000, function () {$("#status").append("<p>div3 done</p>");});
});
var div4 = function() {
    return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
        $(".div4").animate({
        width: "100%"
        }, 1500, dfd.resolve);
    }).promise().done(function () {$("#status").append("<p>div4 done</p>");});
}
$.when(div1, div2, div3, div4()).then(function() {
    $("#status").append("<p>all done</p>");
});
defer.resolve();
```

**html**

```
<div class="div1">div1</div>
<div class="div2">div2</div>
<div class="div3">div3</div>
<div class="div4">div4</div>
<span id="status"></span>
```

Comment: It works fine. You're probably including the wrong version of 3.x (the slim version doesn't have all of the methods)

Comment: @KevinB the order is different it must be `1,4,2,3,all done`. But in `v3` it's `1,2,4,all done,3` which doesn't make sense `when/all done` triggers before `3`. must be at the end after all completed

Comment: Walking through the code, the order you are getting makes sense.

Comment: you need to properly return promises from your .then filters if you expect each one to wait on the previous. https://jsfiddle.net/mrd2dt3a/7/

Comment: @KevinB Great now it works. You may post it as an answer so i can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery 3.0 *"fixed"* the jquery deferred system so that it would more closely follow the Promises/A+ spec. https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#deferred

What this means is now your .then callbacks have to return a thenable, a value, or a rejected promise. jQuery objects aren't thenable, which is why your code started working differently when you upgraded to 3.1.

If you modify your .then() callbacks for 1 2 and 3 to properly return a thenable by adding .promise() to the end, it will go back to working as expected (this works in older versions too.)

```js
/*
JQuery Deferred Objects
*/
var defer = $.Deferred();
var div1 = defer.then(function(value) {
    return $(".div1").animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, 1000).promise();
});
var div2 = div1.then(function(value) {
    $("#status").append("<p>div1 done</p>");
    return $(".div2").animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, 3000).promise();
});
var div3 = div2.then(function(value) {
    $("#status").append("<p>div2 done</p>");
    return $(".div3").animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, 2000, function () {$("#status").append("<p>div3 done</p>");}).promise();
});
var div4 = function() {
    return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
        $(".div4").animate({
  width: "100%"
  }, 1500, dfd.resolve);
    }).promise().done(function () {$("#status").append("<p>div4 done</p>");});
}
$.when(div1, div2, div3, div4()).then(function() {
    $("#status").append("<p>all done</p>");
});
defer.resolve();
```

```css
div {
    width: 0px;
    height: 20px;
}

.div1 {
    background-color: red;
}

.div2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.div3 {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.div4 {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">div1</div>
<div class="div2">div2</div>
<div class="div3">div3</div>
<div class="div4">div4</div>
<span id="status"></span>
```